# Creating a column containing only a specific value of another column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table such as

```
column
abcx sample 6.5oz
bbcd sku 2ct
tty 80z
rre pool 65g box
```

How can I create a new column in my select statement that would just give me what the size of each row value is? ( 6.50z, 2ct, 80z, 65g)

desired output:

```
size
6.5oz
2ct
90z
65g
```

Comment: What. have you tried so far?

Comment: And what are the rules you are actually trying to implement? e.g. select from the first digit to the next space or end of the string?

Comment: Question is not clear... Give a neat table format and what is intended?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not specified precisely.

Here's a solution assuming you're interested in ***"a sequence of digits, possibly containing a dot, immediately followed by a sequence of lowercase letters"***.
If so, this should do it:

```
select col, regexp_substr(col, '[\\d\\.]+[a-z]+') from test;
```

If this is not what you're looking for, please make the question very specific